# Select all objects within a path (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape, selections

I'm currently working with tiled objects (objects that themselves consist of many more smaller objects) with Inkscape. Now it would be so much more easier to not have to select manually all tiles I want to do the same operation with (for example colour, remove) but to be able to select them according to a path that I can paint across/overlay the objects with. Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]
Draw a path on top of objects.

[image]
Colour all objects that the path overlays.

Answer (score 2):

Select nothing, press <kbd>alt</kbd> and then follow the path with your left mouse button being pressed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Scott: Actually, this is an answer. A rather simple one and with some room for improvement, in particular due to the guessing, but definetely an answer.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it wasn't an answer before you edited.. it was commentary.